# загрузка mp3\wav файлов на сервер на java

Tags: java, spring, maven, fileupload

начал изучать spring ,решил сделать приложение на котором лучше пойму как работает он. Хочу написать загрузку аудио файлов на сервер,и выгрузку их в нужном мне формате(wav,mp3 и тд)
Не могу понять с чего начать. Условно - создал проект на maven,указал зависимости и какой следующий шаг? Описывать контроллер сразу?

Comment: `Не могу понять с чего начать` - лучше всего с ручки и блокнота...перед тем как открывать IDE, создавать проект стоит прикинуть что вы собираетесь делать и как...и желательно понимать в общих чертах что вы будете делать от начала и до конца проекта.

Comment: А если не понимаете и не знаете что и как делать, то нужно выявить и конкретизировать все белые пятна: Что именно я не знаю? Что именно я не умею делать? И уже с конкретными вопросами обращаться к нам

Comment: пожалуй Вы правы. Поспешил лезть в иде. Так или иначе - спасибо!